# customize iOS keypad for email address

Tags: ios5

I was able to figure out how to customize the iOS keypad with Previous/Next and Done buttons (as per my github source here: https://github.com/kalvish21/CustomKeyboard). My question is that in Mail (on the iPhone app), it has @ and . near the spacebar so the user can more easily type in their email address. How can I achieve similar functionality? I tried to find something similar online and could not find it...

Is there some API for that as well or is there some example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

`textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress`